# Specifying manual x_range for bokeh vbar

Tags: pandas, bokeh

I'm making a bar chart with bokeh. For that I group some values. The values are responses to a questionnaire (1- very good to  7- very bad). Sometimes, nobody answered "very good". In my bar chart I would like to have empty bars for those not given answers. How do I do that? I thought it would be the x_range parameter, but if I specify that, my plot is empty. My code looks like this:

```
df[answer] = df[answer].astype(str)
group = df.groupby(answer)
source = ColumnDataSource(group)
# with x_range=group, I get a graph, but without empty bars
p = figure(plot_height=350, x_range=[0, 7])
p.vbar(x=answer, top='SurveyId_count', width=0.9, source=source)
p.y_range.start = 0
save(p)
```

I also tried x_range=(1,7) or such, but it doesn't yield the result I want.

Answer (score 0):

Categorical factors are strings. Additionally, when making a categorical range you must supply *all the factors, explicitly, yourself*. By coincidence your factors happen to look similar to a range of numbers, but in general categorical factors are actually arbitrary names, there is no way for Bokeh to know what they are unless you tell it.

Since you haven't provided a complete example that can be run, it's not possible for me to provide an answer that is actually tested, but you probably want something like:

```
x_range = [str(x) for x in range(1,8)]
```